# FPDF isn't working (font error)

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, fpdf

I wanted to try out FPDF, with **XAMPP** it works perfectly, but as I upload it to my webserver, it says an error:

> Warning: include(/font/helveticab.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php on line 1147 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/font/helveticab.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php on line 1147 Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Could not include font definition file in /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php:275 Stack trace: #0 /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php(1149): FPDF->Error('Could not inclu...') #1 /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php(463): FPDF->_loadfont('helveticab.php') #2 /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php(511): FPDF->AddFont('helvetica', 'B') #3 /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/rechnung.php(14): FPDF->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 15) #4 /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php(338): PDF->Header() #5 /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/rechnung.php(65): FPDF->AddPage() #6 {main} thrown in /customers/9/f/c/dynamistic.de/httpd.www/websites/testauftrag/fpdf.php on line 275

This is the fpdf.php part which causes the error:

```html
protected function _loadfont($font)
{
 // Load a font definition file from the font directory
 if(strpos($font,'/')!==false || strpos($font,"\\")!==false)
  $this->Error('Incorrect font definition file name: '.$font);
 include($this->fontpath.$font);
 if(!isset($name))
  $this->Error('Could not include font definition file');
 if(isset($enc))
  $enc = strtolower($enc);
 if(!isset($subsetted))
  $subsetted = false;
 return get_defined_vars();
}
```

Comment: It's quite obvious, does `/font/helveticab.php` exist ?

Comment: yes, it does, if you want to, I can upload the whole folder

Comment: From your log, your path is probably `font/helveticab.php` instead of `/font/helveticab.php`. Wrong path.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem